# Storing multiple values in an array using Button

Tags: python, html, arrays, flask

In my HTML Page I have a dropdown and a button, how can i add/store my chosen schedule in my dropdown menu inside an array everytime im going to click the button.

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="/dashboard/">
<label for="sel2" style="font-size: 1em;">Schedule:</label>
 <div class="row">
   <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="sel2" name="time_select[]" style="width: 13%;">
       <option value="" selected data-default>Select Schedule:</option>
          {% for j in john %}
          <option value="{{ j.name }}">{{ j.name }}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">ADD</button>
  </div>
```

Flask App:

```
@app.route('/dashboard/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def dashboard():
  if request.method == 'POST':
     if request.form['submit'] == 'add':
         name3 = request.form.get('time_select[]')
         pass
```

but this flask app code gives me an error, is there anyway in storing multiple values in an array using a button.

Comment: Simply add [the `multiple` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) to your select element.